# phpAdmin shows rows, MySQL statement doesn't?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

**EDIT**
Provided as requested is here how the Date column looks:
Jan 15, 2014
Jan 16, 2014
Aug 10, 2014

So what i am trying to achieve, is extract every row that contains Jan 2014, so i get every row for that month in that year.

Here is my PHP code that generates the query:

```
    $monthYearString = $month . "%" . $year;
$query_current = "SELECT * FROM {$table_omsaetning} WHERE 'Date' LIKE " . "'{$monthYearString}'";
echo $query_current;
```

The echo gives me this query:  SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE 'Date' LIKE 'Jan%2014'

**Original question**

I have a very weird issue here.
If i perform a search using phpAdmin provided by my hosting site, and search for rows that are like a certain date, it conjures up this SQL statement, and it finds 3 rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table_name` 
WHERE  `Date` LIKE  'Jan%2014'
```

BUT, when I try to do the same thing either using SQL statements in phpAdmin or my own code, it shows NOTHING? How come? It is 100% the same statement. Really can't understand how I can search using the built-in phpAdmin function, and then it generates that SQL statement, and then when I try to inject it myself, it just returns 0 rows instead of 3.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: not Jan%2014. use `%Jan-2014%`

Comment: What exactly is stored in the `Date` column? What is its type, and what are examples of the actual data there?

Comment: @Seerex Can you post the schema of your table?

Comment: Can you post the PHP code where you generate this query and read the results

Comment: Posted both the date column info and my php code. THanks everyone

Comment: try this: `mysql_query('your query here') or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between single quotes and backticks is important here. You have quoted your column name instead of using backticks. It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name_here WHERE `Date` LIKE 'Jan%2014'
```

The backtick character (see the `Date` column in the query above) allows you to indicate it's a name rather than a string. In this case, if you didn't have these, you would get an error because `Date` is a reserved word. The backtick allows you to use reserved words for table and column names.

Where as the single quote means it's a string. In the case of your query, you were essentially searching for any records where the string `'Date'` contains the string `'January 2014'` which isn't possible and will always return zero results.

For more information, check out this SO question: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Your code should look like this:

```
$monthYearString = $month . "%" . $year;
$query_current = "SELECT * FROM {$table_omsaetning} WHERE `Date` LIKE '{$monthYearString}'";
echo $query_current;
```

Comment: Wauw, thanks a LOT man. i was NEVER gonna get that on my own. Really really great answer, with good explanation and a link to further study + how to correct my code. I couldn't ask for more! Thanks a ton for both answering, and guiding me in the proper direction for more knowledge on the subject.